# not registered on network error in android

Tags: android

I have written following code to make a call also have set permissions in manifest file. But when I am trying to call I got **not registered on network** error. I have googled it. But didnot get solution. Please help me

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                + callingNumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

I have set call phone permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I got this problem in Emulator (Android-2.1)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: try on a phone, may get u over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my eclipse. relaunched it. It is working fine now.

Thanks